# USB Over Network for Windows/Linux

Tags: windows, linux, remote-access, usb

I need to plug my USB device in my Windows machine and have it read/accessed by the client which is a Linux machine without the client knowing it is not local.

I have found the [USB/IP Project](http://usbip.sourceforge.net) which only supports  Linux as the server.

I have also found commercial products that provide Windows to be the server such as:

- [usb-over-network](http://www.usb-over-network.com/)
- [net-usb](https://www.net-usb.com/)

But I am looking for a free stable project.